# How to find out why renameTo() failed?

Tags: java, file, file-io, file-rename

I am using WinXP. I use java to generate a list of files. The file will be created as abc.txt.temp at first, and after completing the generation, it will be renamed to abc.txt.

However, when i generating the files, some of the files failed to be renamed. It happen randomly.

Is there anyway to find out the reason why it failed?

```java
int maxRetries = 60;
logger.debug("retry");
while (maxRetries-- > 0)
{
    if (isSuccess = file.renameTo(file2))
    {
        break;
    }
    try
    {
        logger.debug("retry " + maxRetries);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

//file.renameTo(file2);
Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getParent().list();
```

And the result:

```
[DEBUG][2009-08-25 08:57:52,386] - retry 1
[DEBUG][2009-08-25 08:57:53,386] - retry 0
java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]
    Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
    Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
    Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
    Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]
    java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
        Thread[main,5,main]
        Thread[log4j mail appender,5,main]
[DEBUG][2009-08-25 08:57:54,386] - isSuccess:false
```

I would like to know a systematic approach to figure out the reason. Thanks.

Comment: Are you catching any exceptions that are thrown?

Comment: no. no exception at all. It only returns false.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use of multiple threads here? This sounds like a race condition, but without more information I can't begin to guess the actual point of failure.

Comment: I didn't create any new thread in my program. I just check if any thread has been created without my knowledge.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's possible that the reason that renaming failed is that the file is still open. Even if you are closing the file, it could be held open because of (for example):

1. A file handle is inherited by a subprocess of your process
2. An anti-virus program is scanning the file for viruses, and so has it open
3. An indexer (such as Google Desktop or the Windows indexing service) has the file open

To help find out what is keeping the file open, use tools such as [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) and [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx).

**Update:** A tool such as Unlocker may not help, if the file is only held open for a very short time (as would be the case for an anti-virus scan). However, if javaw.exe is shown as having the file open, that's your problem right there.

Comment: I am using Unlocker. and it only shows "javaw.exe" as the only locker. :(

Comment: I would think that scanning applications like anti-virus and indexers shouldn't be able to hold the file and prevent it from being altered or renamed... Is this actually the case in WinXP?

Comment: They don't hold the file open for long, but typically watch for file changes and scan after updates to the file. If you write to a file, close it and then try to rename it, the file *could* still be held open at that point (though not for long).

Answer (score 3):

If no exceptions were thrown (I'm assuming you would have noticed that) `renameTo()` only returns true or false to indicate whether the rename succeeded or not and doesn't give any additional information.

Since it's Windows, a failure most likely indicates the the file is currently in use. This would happen because some other process has it open. More likely though, your process either isn't finished writing it or you forgot to close the file after you were done writing it.

It is also possible that you passed in an invalid path, or the gave a non-existent path to the `File` constructor.

`renameTo()` will only throw exceptions if there is a security violation (`SecurityException`) or if you pass in a `null` for the file to rename.

Comment: I know it returns false, but it gives no clue why it failed.

I've closed all the outputStream.close() & set it to null. But it still failed randomly. Let's say I generated 10 files, file0.tmp ... file9.tmp, it might be file5.tmp failed to change to file5.txt.

Answer (score 3):

```
File o=new File("d:/old.txt");
File n=new File("d:/new.txt");
n.delete();
o.renameTo(n);
```

`n.delete()`  :   We need to delete the file(new.txt) if exists.

`o.rename(n)` :   so that the file(old.txt) is renamed as new.txt

Comment: I did that very thing and still got false back from rename. The file was closed and nothing else had it. Windows. Just... Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but this is with unix.
The rename randomly failed. I restarted the process 3 to 4 times and finally went to success.
FYI the file was created by the same process and the same process renames it..

Answer (score 2):

Three Major reasons renameTo can fail (for Android, but you may also find this useful)!

1) If you are moving folders from place a to place b, the destination folder may be a file! Make the destinationFolder.mkdirs() to make it a file!

2) The destination folder may already exist! Delete the destinationFolder so that you can use renameTo to move the old file to that new location

3) Moving internal storage to external storage requires permission, because reading and writing to SD card requires permission!

Comment: I found this question via Google, and #2 was my issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Make the destinationFolder.mkdirs() to make it a file!" Huh?

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that you may not rename the file because you don't have sufficient permissions. On Unix, that's simple. On Win10, well... see e.g. https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1911-take-ownership-shortcut.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing on Mac. I have a process that creates 163,000 files in a single thread. It skips creating any file that already exists. To avoid a partial file problem, when it comes time to write the file, it writes a temp file (.../dir/tmp.filename) and then renames it (.../dir/filename).

I ran it once (from inside IntelliJ), and then the run window disappeared, which was odd. I restarted IntelliJ and ran it again, and started getting errors on a bunch (but not all) of my file renames. It turned out that my previously-running java process was still running, even though IntelliJ (which had launched it) had quit. So I had two processes looking for the existence of the same files and stepping on each others' toes.

Answer (score -4):

File f=new File(folder+file);
verify with if you have write correct path.. 
f.exists();
else is exist and return false verify with procMon if is looked..