# File extension not changing - Android

Tags: java, android, file, rename, file-rename

I'm trying to create an app in Android, and part of it's functionality is renaming `.jpg` file extensions to `.jpeg` file extensions. However, it's not working.

`filepath` is the path of the `.jpg` file, and `doThings()` is what it does after the file has been renamed.

Here is my code:

```
// Create new string to store edited file path
String newfilepath = filepath;

// Create new file to be used for renaming
File file1 = new File(filepath);

// Remove JPG extension
newfilepath = newfilepath.substring(0, newfilepath.length() - 3);

// Replace with JPEG extension
newfilepath += "jpeg";

// Add new file for renaming purposes
File file2 = new File(newfilepath);

// Rename file from JPG to JPEG
boolean rename = file1.renameTo(file2);

// Check if file renaming was successful
if(rename) {
    // Does things
    doThings(newfilepath);
}
```

Note: I also tried changing `file1.renameTo(file2);` to this:

```
boolean test = file1.renameTo(file2);
System.out.println("Renamed? " + test);
```

And received this in logcat:

```
I/System.out: Renamed? false
```

Also, to prove it's not a permissions issue, here is the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And I do request permissions in the Android 6+ format here:

```
public void getPermissions(View view) {
    String[] perms = { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
        // We have permissions, send message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Select an image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        selectFile();
    } else {
        // We don't have permissions
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Ask again
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                perms, PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I've been testing and getting weird results. I will update this later today.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325388/how-to-find-out-why-renameto-failed

Comment: How do you close a file? There is no `file1.close()` in Java.

Comment: No. But if you just created the file you would have used FileOutputStream and not closed the stream?

Comment: Of course you should always check if renameTo() succeeds before calling doThings(). Normal! And display a toast if it does not! Please tell which full path is it exactly?

Comment: I would also add a file1.exists() check before calling renameTo().

Comment: Where is the file located? `renameTo` will not work for removable SD cards.

Comment: Is there a way to rename files on a removable SD card? @JaredRummler